# I am trying to use Clarifai api in my application, but getting an error saying that "cannot resolve symbol"

Tags: android, clarifai

I am trying to use Clarifai API in my application, but getting an error saying that "cannot resolve symbol"

```
final List<ClarifaiOutput<Concept>> predictionResults = Clarifai.getDefaultModels()
.generalModel()
.predict()
.withInputs(
     ClarifaiInput.forImage(
         ClarifaiImage.of("https://samples.clarifai.com/metro-north.jpg")
     )
).executeSync()
```

It is saying

> not able to resolve symbol Clarifai

Comment: Please look here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask as how to ask a question on SO

Comment: @Jadeye What exactly is wrong with the question?

Comment: some information is lacking.....like the answers you;re getting - no import statement or init.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like something wasn't imported correctly here. Make sure you're following all of the steps outlined at:

https://github.com/Clarifai/clarifai-java

Answer (score 0):

`Clarifai` is not a class in that repository...  https://github.com/Clarifai/clarifai-java

AFAIK, you need to use create a `ClarifaiBuilder`, then call `build()` on that, and **then** you can call `getDefaultModels()`

---

From the unit tests.

```
  @NotNull final ClarifaiClient client = new ClarifaiBuilder(appID, appSecret)
      .baseURL(baseURL)
      .client(new OkHttpClient.Builder()
          .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
          .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
          .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
          .addInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor(System.out::println).setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY))
          .build()
      )
      .buildSync();
```

...

```
  @Test public void quickStartPredict() {
    final ClarifaiResponse<List<ClarifaiOutput<Concept>>> predictionResults =
        client.getDefaultModels().generalModel() // You can also do client.getModelByID("id") to get custom models
            .predict()
            .withInputs(
                ClarifaiInput.forImage(ClarifaiImage.of("@@sampleTrain"))
            )
            .executeSync();
  }
```

Comment: okay i got it thanks for the help.. i have tried it and now my code is working